# running mongoexport from inside one container to another within a docker-compose stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mongoexport

I'm building a CMS that needs to export mongodb data in json format and return it as a .zip file to an api request.

I have a service called "web" and I'm needing to run

```
const child = exec(`mongoexport --db meanbase --collection pages --out ${path.join(this.app.get('exportPath'), 'pages.json')} --jsonArray`)
```

However it returns code 127 - command not found. This is because my mongoDB service is running inside another container.

```
db:
  image: mongo
  expose:
    - "27017"
    - "37017"
  command: --smallfiles
web:
  build: .
  expose:
    - "80"
  env_file:
    - meanbase.env
  links:
      - db:db
nginx:
  build: nginx
  links:
    - web:web
  volumes_from:
    - web
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

How do I run mongoexport from my web container for the db container and get it's content delivered back to the the web container? Or is there a better way to be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the `mongoexport` command doesn't exist in the `web` container. You need to install it the `Dockerfile` for the `web` service.